# Saved file changes in editor lost when disconnected using X forwarding over SSH

Tags: debian, ssh, x11, xorg, xforwarding

I have a very strange problem on a debian stable server:

There is a file opened in a text editor on the remote machine using X11 forwarding over SSH.
The file changes were supposedly saved to disk using the save button.
The SSH disconnected because of a network error.

When reconnected, the file changes are reverted to original state.

Is there some kind of caching on the OS level?

(How could I gather more information, what logs / configs should I check?)

Edit: This is not the first time this happened.

Comment: It would be up to the editor to save the file when it loses its connection to the X server. What editor is this? Did you try restarting the editor to see if it saved a copy of the changes somewhere?

Comment: @Kenster so this sounds like 100% the editor's fault? There should be no additional level of cache after `fwrite(..., fp); fclose(fp);` that is lost on SSH disconnect?